# Unity Wifi GUI - Connects ok, but doesn't display any other networks

Tags: networking, unity, wireless, 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad Y560.  The wifi automatically connects upon startup to the network I've been using, which is good.  However, I can't find a way to display other networks that are in range.

Is this just how the Unity GUI works - there's no way to select a network?  That doesn't seem right - I'm sure I've seen screenshots of the GUI showing a list of networks.  Or is this a hardware issue?  The wireless adaptor seems to be working fine, as I'm connected, and the terminal correctly displays wireless networks that are in range.

More info:

In the terminal, I can show that the computer detects a whole bunch of wireless networks that the GUI doesn't display.  Here's the output of `iwlist wlp5s0 s | grep SSID`

```
                ESSID:"Libbetshouse"
                ESSID:""
                ESSID:""
                ESSID:"xfinitywifi"
                ESSID:"NETGEAR06_2GEXT"
                ESSID:""
                ESSID:""
                ESSID:"NETGEAR06"
                ESSID:"HOME-5F11-2.4"
                ESSID:"xfinitywifi"
                ESSID:"HOME-8402"
                ESSID:""
                ESSID:"xfinitywifi"
                ESSID:"Steadfast"
```

Here's the output of `lshw -class network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 01
       serial: c0:cb:38:8d:6b:69
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.95 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f8900000-f890ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 01
       serial: 60:eb:69:b6:c8:85
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=half firmware=sb v2.07 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:f8a00000-f8a0ffff
```

Finally, here's a screenshot of the networking drop-down menu when I am connected to the wifi network I've been using (notice that no other networks are displayed):

[image: screenshot for wifi]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that has yet to be fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1569959

In the meantime, restarting Network-Manager usually corrects it (until the next time you suspend or reboot):

`sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`

Comment: That does work in the meantime!!  Thank you so much for the work-around!

Comment: @redoak To make it a little less annoying, you might consider making an alias for that command, rather than having to enter the whole thing into the terminal each time.